# How to have all my classes default functionalities like .ToString method

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I want to have all my classes some set of behaviour like all classes in .net (ToString, GetHashCode etc.) have.
But I don't want to create a base class which have these type of functions and inherit all the classes from this base class. By going this way I will lost the liberty of inherting my classes from any other class (since .net support inheritance from only one class).

How .net framework create a class without inherting from base object class but has virtual behaivour in all classes?

We don't write like this

```
class MyClass : System.Object
{
}
```

but MyClass gets virtual functions of System.Object.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to explicitly declare that your class inherits from `System.Object` because the compiler will enforce that your class derive from `System.Object` automatically if you do not want to do so manually for it could become very tedious.

You can confirm this yourself by declaring a class in your code and then disassembling the assembly output by the compiler.  I declared a class `class Person { }` and disassembled the output. The following IL was produced

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Code.Person
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
```

If you want to define some common functionality amongst your classes without a base class then you might consider writing an extension method on `System.Object`

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void DoSomething(this object target)
    {

    }
}
```

You could be more explicit yet and define an interface that your classes could implement and then define the extension method for said interface. Because there are no limitiations to how many interfaces you can implement this might mitigate your concerns about multiple inheritance.

Comment: This would work for arbitrary behaviors, but not for the methods the OP mentions (`ToString` and `GetHashCode`) because they are virtual methods.  You can't override a virtual method with an extension method.  I know you are suggesting to use an alternate name, but that would defeat the purpose in the case of, e.g. `GetHashCode`, which is used by the framework.

Comment: @harpo then he must use a master base class everything else inherits from, it already happens in like in the OP, all classes that have no base class have a implicit `System.Object` added. He will just need to add whatever "master class" he wants and manually have his classes inherit from it. The job could be made easier by creating a [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) so by default Visual Studio adds your special class for you whenever you create a new file.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, yes, that is what I'd recommend.  However, the OP states that this should be done without a master class.  I think that is based on a misunderstanding, though.

Answer (score 0):

To build on ByteBlast's post and address harpo's concern, you could use decorator interfaces with extension methods.

```
public interface IMyDecorator{}
public interface IMySecondDecorator : IMyDecorator {}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Print(this IMyDecorator target)
    {
    }
    public static void Print(this IMySecondDecorator target)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: How does using interfaces change the situation?

Comment: Because Puneet can now implement the appropriate interface which corresponds to the extension method that he wants to use. He did specify that he is working on his classes and not all classes and the only restriction is that he did not want to limit himself to deriving from a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want to have done can be accomplished with [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/)? Essentially have the tool replace all classes which inherit from System.Object with an inheritance from your custom class?

Comment: OP wants the freedom to inherit from something other than their own base class (presumably classes that are not part of their code, framework types, types from 3rd party libraries). This would work for things that inherit from `System.Object` but not for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question, but I think the answer is, you can't.  If you're not willing to use a universal base class, then you cannot provide universal behavior for methods inherited from `object`.

If this really matters to you, then it's worth considering the base class route.  Of course, you can't make it apply to framework classes, but those are sealed (or invisible) in many cases anyway.

I have been thinking about this question because I'm working with a few classes that do nothing but provide `GetHashCode` and `Equals` overrides for classes with value-type semantics.  In several cases, it would be very handy to use an alternate base class, but you simply cannot override those behaviors by any other means (e.g. interfaces/extension methods).

Answer (score 0):

A universal base class is the obvious answer to this problem but will not provide the 'standard' implementation for classes that inherit from types outside of your application's class hierarchy.

I would consider [composition in place of inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). This is the essence of what has been proposed by @ByteBlast and @PhilipScottGivens.

Why not have a helper class that provides the functionality for you `GetHashCode` and `ToString` methods (I am picturing some reflection in both of these so that you can work with the members / properties of the instances of your types) and whatever other common services you require for all objects?

An instance of this (or maybe the helper has static methods that you pass an instance to - much like the extension methods) is passed into each object or created by the instance of your object.